# Python DataFrame, unable to separate attributes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a Python code that trains a dataset to identify whether a news item is fake or true. I need to be able to put the data into columns, i.e. attributes and the target. The **"is sarcastic"** column, which has a value of either 1 or 0, is the target. The **"headline"** and the **"article_link"** columns are the attributes. The dataset is huge, comprising of thousands of rows. I have shown below just three of those rows. My problem is this: given a raw JSON file, I converted it into a CSV file which can be read in Excel. But when I display the data in Python, the attributes are not separated, they are lumped together in ONE column, and I do not know how to disentangle them. Here's a part of my code (I have not listed all my imports or sklearns):

```
import pandas as pd

from pandas import DataFrame

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

file1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\JohnBoy\Downloads\fake.csv", sep='delimiter', header=None, engine='python')

file2 = pd.DataFrame(file1)

print(file2)

file2.shape

file2.head()

file2.columns.values

Now, below is the raw JSON file which I later converted to CSV: 

{"is_sarcastic": 1, "headline": "thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday clock of hair loss", "article_link": "https://www.theonion.com/thirtysomething-scientists-unveil-doomsday-clock-of-hai-1819586205"}
{"is_sarcastic": 0, "headline": "dem rep. totally nails why congress is falling short on gender, racial equality", "article_link": "https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/donna-edwards-inequality_us_57455f7fe4b055bb1170b207"}
{"is_sarcastic": 0, "headline": "eat your veggies: 9 deliciously different recipes", "article_link": "https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/eat-your-veggies-9-delici_b_8899742.html"}
```

Below is what I see in my Jupyter Notebook when I run the Python code above (I'm showing just three rows here):

```
                        0

0               "is_sarcastic","headline","article_link"

1      1,"thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday ...

2      0,"dem rep. totally nails why congress is fall...

3      0,"eat your veggies: 9 deliciously different r...

       **[11205 rows x 1 columns]**
       array([0], dtype=int64)
```

When I type:

```
df1.headline

df1.head()
```

I get the Error message: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'headline'. This clearly means that instead of 3 columns, I just have one column (and you can clearly see that is the case where it says 11205 rows x 1 columns). What am I doing wrong? I don't seem to be able to separate my columns.

[Data as they appear in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZI80.png)

Comment: As an aside, accessing columns using `.` is a bad habit. `.values` also shouldn’t be used, IIRC. Why are you creating a DataFrame from `file_1`? `file_1` is already a DataFrame. Are you sure that the JSON -> CSV conversion caused no issues?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Yes, I realized that file1 was already in DataFrame format. But my problem really is that the CSV file looks ok in Excel, but when that file is opened in Python, commas start appearing and the attributes cannot be accessed. I have searched the Web for answers but have come up empty.

Comment: Can you share some of the CSV data?

Comment: Hi Alexander. I'm brand new to Stackoverflow. I've just pasted the first three rows of my Excel spreadsheet. Can you see it?

Comment: Yes, sort of lol Where do you define `df1`?

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `file1`?

Comment: Sorry, I understand your confusion. df1 was the variable used on a website https://data-flair.training/blogs/advanced-python-project-detecting-fake-news/. I meant file2.headline and file2.head().

Comment: Yes, the output of file1 is as shown above in Jupyter Notebook above (in the main question section above).

Comment: This is bizarre. Is there anyway you could share just the straight CSV data? Doesn’t even have to be the entire file.

Comment: Also, I don’t understand the use of `sep=‘delimiter’`.

Answer (score 0):

The method `read_csv()` of pandas module returns DataFrame object. So your line to construct `file2 = pd.DataFrame(file1)` is totally unnecessary.

Secondly, when you open a `.csv` file you need to specify separator/delimiter arg:`sep`(a character that divides data into columns in a row) which is incorrectly specifie in your `file1` construction.

Since you specified you seen comma when opened in Excel, delimiter is comma in your case.

And you have set `header` is None. If you have header in first row in your csv, then it should be 0 (index of row).

So your code should be,
`file1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\JohnBoy\Downloads\fake.csv", sep=',', header=0, engine='python')`

Thirdly, when opening csv files in Excel, open a blank sheet, then go Data > select Import from Text Data > Select your csv file. You will then see delimiter options to process your data. On selecting comma, you will be able to view properly in Excel.

Comment: Amageswaran, thanks for your reply. Please allow me to clarify, the commas were NOT seen in Excel. In Excel, everything was as it should be. It's only when that CSV file was imported/opened in Python that commas appeared. Also, I have just tried what you suggested, that is, replacing the word 'delimiter' with a comma, i.e. sep = ',' but that gave me a parsing error -- ParserError: ',' expected after '"'.

Comment: @JohnRambo understood. strange though. can you try with no ```header``` arg and with ```header=0``` arg you still have issues..

Comment: definitely its to do with the delimiter character. please copy paste here the exact new lines you are using when you got the parse error.

Comment: Amageswaran, when I use the line                                                                                                                                             file1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\JohnBoy\Downloads\fake.csv", sep='delimiter', header=None, engine='python')  I do not get an error. However, when I use                                                                                  
  file1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\JohnBoy\Downloads\fake.csv", sep=',', header=None, engine='python')    I get a parsing error.

Comment: Also, I have no header. I think that is the problem. The row that contains the name of my attributes and target is being treated as "data", which it shouldn't be. Also, I changed header = None to header = 0 to see if it would make any difference, it didn't. I still got AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'headline'

Comment: @JohnRambo The header shouldn’t be an issue at this point. Specify `header=0` (I think), and define your column names and `dtype`s manually. Don’t forget to indicate the `quotechar`.

Comment: @JohnRambo. If you still have problem, please attach your CSV file or copy paste first 3-4 lines after opening in Notepad.